# Where can I find a speed comparison between xquery processors, specifically Saxon & Zorba?

Tags: performance, saxon, zorba

I have found feature comparisons but not speed comparisons.

Saxon is written in Java and I believe Zorba is written in C so one would expect Zorba to be quicker, but is it?

Comment: Worth noting that while Java startup is slower if you don't already have a JVM running, once that initialization is over, all bets are off.  The only way to get reliable information about performance is to measure it, on the data you care about, with the queries you care about, in the environment you care about.  Trust no one who says there is a simple or general answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run some benchmarks here: http://xqbench.org

Since for a long time nobody answered to this post, I try to give some parts of the answer. But please consider that I am probably biased since I am working on Zorba.

First of all I try to make some general notes:

- Zorba is written in C++ and Saxon in Java - but the programming language is by no way an indication that one is faster than the other.
- While Zorba is licensed under the Apache license Saxon has another licensing model. It is safe to say that the commercial Saxon version (i.e. Saxon-EE) is much faster than the open source version. Also (AFAIK) the open source version misses a lot of features from the commercial one.
- Comparing the speed of two XQuery engines is extremely difficult. In the end it will depend very much on the use-case. It is easy for me to write down some queries that run faster in Saxon than in Zorba and vice versa.

As long as you don't provide any information about your use case it is probably not possible to answer your question in a helpful way. These are questions you should probably ask yourself:

- What kind of features do you need (XQuery 1.0, Schema support, XQuery 3.0, XQuery Update facility, XQuery Scripting extension, fancy modules, Java integration, C/C++ integration etc)?
- Does Zorba meet the requirements and which Saxon versions meet the requirements?
- Are you willing to pay money (and Saxon is for sure a software worth some money)?

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. Do you know where I can get hold of a binary of Zorba for Windows? I am not a C programmer and compiling Zorba from source is beyond my ability. I could then run my own speed tests.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zorba/files/zorba/1.4.0/ - there is a Windows binary for version 1.4.0 - which is quite an old version. We are heavily working on the 2.0 release which should go public very soon (i.e. most probably this month). Consider that Zorba runs slower on Windows than on Linux (we do not know why yet) and that Zorba 2.0 will be much faster (there will be a Windows installer for Zorba 2.0 for sure).

Answer (score 0):

regarding my personal experiences, I'd claim that Saxon is much faster than Zorba in nearly all cases. However, another great XQuery processor worth looking at is BaseX (http://basex.org). It performs even better in many cases, even if no databases are created for the addressed XML documents.

Best regards,
Hannes Bauer